# Python Tkinter multiple frames with background image

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and I'm struggling with what should be quite a simple bit of python code for my RasPi. My objective is to have a series of frames that all have the same fixed size and background image but have different buttons, labels (on top of the image) and functions. If I include a canvas and an image in the container then I can get my frames (well the first frame at least) to show the background image but I can't add anything to the canvas from the page specific class because I can't reference the canvas anymore?? If I leave the frames blank in the container then add the canvas/image in the page specific class then I can't get the canvas/image to work. This is the code that I'm trying to modify to suit my needs...

```
import Tkinter as tk

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page",                    font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page", 
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page", 
                       command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working...

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Saffi.gif")
        BGlabel = tk.Label(self,image=logo)
        BGlabel.image = logo
        BGlabel.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=450)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=44)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page two", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                        command=self.quit)
        button1.place(x=100,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button2.place(x=300,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button3.place(x=500,y=406,width=80,height=44)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Saffi.gif")
        BGlabel = tk.Label(self,image=logo)
        BGlabel.image = logo
        BGlabel.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=450)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=44)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    #button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page two", 
     #                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                        command=self.quit)
        button1.place(x=100,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button3.place(x=300,y=406,width=200,height=44)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        logo = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Saffi.gif")
        BGlabel = tk.Label(self,image=logo)
        BGlabel.image = logo
        BGlabel.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=450)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page two", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=44)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page", 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    #button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page two", 
     #                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                        command=self.quit)
        button1.place(x=100,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button3.place(x=300,y=406,width=200,height=44)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```