# Tkinter switch between multiple frames python

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I state that I'm trying to apply the solution proposed here [Solution by Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249931/python-tkinter-multiple-frames-with-background-image), so as to create more frames but I can not enter the code and the error I receive in the console.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import secondpage

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, secondpage.PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=44)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page two",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(secondpage.PageTwo))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                        command=self.quit)
        button1.place(x=100,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button2.place(x=300,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button3.place(x=500,y=406,width=80,height=44)


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page one", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=44)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    #button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page two",
     #                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                        command=self.quit)
        button1.place(x=100,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button3.place(x=300,y=406,width=200,height=44)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

And this is the second page that i would to create

```
import Tkinter as tk
import GUIprova

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page two", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.place(x=0,y=0,width=592,height=44)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Start Page",
                            command=lambda: SampleApp.show_frame(GUIprova.StartPage))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Exit",
                        command=self.quit)
        button1.place(x=100,y=406,width=200,height=44)
        button3.place(x=300,y=406,width=200,height=44)
```

this is the exception

- > Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File
  >   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
  >   line 1541, in **call**
  >       return self.func(*args)   File "/Users/Antonello/PycharmProjects/GUI/secondpage.py", line 19, in
  >   
  >       command=lambda: SampleApp.show_frame(StartPage)) TypeError: unbound method show_frame() must be called with SampleApp instance as
  >   first argument (got classobj instance instead)

can someone help me? I should also insert other buttons in the second frame, how can I do?

Comment: Please narrow down your question and create [mcve](s) for it.

Comment: You're trying to use `show_frame` as if it is a class method, it is not defined as such, it is a regular method on an instance _of_ the class. So `...command=lambda: SampleApp.show_frame(GUIprova.StartPage))` should instead be `...command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GUIprova.StartPage))` in order to fix the immediate error.

Comment: thank you @Nae but it's doesn't work. This is the exception: "File "/Users/Antonello/PycharmProjects/GUI/GUIprova.py", line 24, in show_frame
    frame = self.frames[c]
KeyError: <class GUIprova.StartPage at 0x1005bc808>"

Comment: There is no __self.frames[c]__ in any of the code posted.

Comment: @CurlyJoe That is _untrue_ the top-most code does refer to it.

Comment: Ah yes.  The error occurs because self.frames contains class instances, not frames that can be raised (note that in my code below we get the frame from the class instance and append it).  If you print self.frames you will see that it contains things like what was printed int the error message, i.e. class instances KeyError: __<class GUIprova.StartPage at 0x1005bc808>__ and none of them look anything like PageOne which will print something like __<class 'main .PageOne'>__ if you print(PageOne).  I hope you are beginning to understand why this code is crap.

Answer (score 1):

An example of adding a function, and a button to call it, to one of the classes (PageOne), but you should be able to figure this out for yourself.

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

class SampleApp():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.button_dict={}
        self.frame_dict={}
        self.create_buttons()
        self.start_page_frame()

        for classname, lit in [(PageOne, "PageOne"), (PageTwo, "PageTwo")]:
            instance=classname(root)
            self.frame_dict[lit]=instance.page_frame

    def button_press(self, button_id):
        print(button_id)
        ## deselect current frame's button, and activate all others
        for key in self.button_dict:
            if key==button_id:
                self.button_dict[key].config(state="disabled")
            else:
                self.button_dict[key].config(state="normal")

        ## raise the frame corresponding to the button clicked
        self.frame_dict[button_id].lift()

    def create_buttons(self):
        """ you can also use a simple for() to create these
        """
        self.button_frame=tk.Frame(self.root)
        self.button_frame.grid(row=10, column=0)

        button0 = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Go to Start Page",
                            bg="lightblue", width=15,
                            command=partial(self.button_press, "StartPage"))
        button0.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.button_dict["StartPage"]=button0

        button1 = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Go to Page One",
                            bg="yellow", width=15, 
                            command=partial(self.button_press, "PageOne"))
        button1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ew")
        self.button_dict["PageOne"]=button1

        button2 = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Go to Page two",
                            bg="lightgreen", width=15,
                            command=partial(self.button_press, "PageTwo"))
        button2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ew")
        self.button_dict["PageTwo"]=button2
        button2.config(state="disabled")

        button_quit = tk.Button(self.button_frame, text="Exit", bg="orange",
                                command=self.root.quit)
        button_quit.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="ewns")

    def start_page_frame(self):
        start_frame=tk.Frame(self.root, width=25, height=25)
        tk.Label(start_frame,  width=24, bg="lightblue",
                text="This is the start page").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        start_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
        self.frame_dict["StartPage"]=start_frame

class PageOne():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ## frame must be named self.page_frame to work in for() above
        self.page_frame=tk.Frame(parent)
        self.label_text=tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self.page_frame,  width=24,
                         textvariable=self.label_text,
                         bg="yellow").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.label_text.set("This is page one")
        self.page_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.ctr=0
        tk.Button(self.page_frame, text="Change label text",
                  command=self.change_label_text).grid(row=5, column=0)


    def change_label_text(self):
        text_list=["this is page one", "new message page one",
                   "third message for page one"]
        self.ctr += 1
        if self.ctr >= len(text_list):
            self.ctr=0
        self.label_text.set(text_list[self.ctr])

class PageTwo():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ## frame must be named self.page_frame to work in for() above
        self.page_frame=tk.Frame(parent, width=25, height=25)
        label = tk.Label(self.page_frame,  width=24,
                         text="This is page two",
                         bg="lightgreen").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
        self.page_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")

root=tk.Tk()
SA=SampleApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I thank you but if I wanted to create another class for example ("first frame") in another python file, how should I proceed? I did not succeed, this is the guy.py https://codepaste.net/4cncnr and this is FirstFrame.py https://codepaste.net/6qwtei